# Using a Spring boot application as dependency in Sonarqube plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I have a Spring boot application (myApp) that I want to use as a dependency (library) inside a Sonarqube Plugin. I have created  the non-FAT myApp.jar and added it as a dependency to the Sonarqube plugin's pom.xml file. But while running the plugin, getting this following error.

**no auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories**

I have also added the correct spring.factories file in resource folder of the myApp project, but
the error still happening.  I know it a bit complex to add a Spring boot jar inside a non-spring application, but I was successful doing that for some other project, but its not working for Sonarqube plugin; not sure if sonar-packaging-maven plugin is the one who blocking this from using spring framework in the project.
The plugin api I am using is Sonarqube 7.2 and Spring boot version is 2.2.2 RELEASE.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-FAT"? You mean it is not following format?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.htm

Comment: Spring boot maven plugin creates 2 jars. One is a FAT executable jar containing all the dependencies, but it cant be added as a dependency to another non spring project.  The second jar is the normal non executable jar which we generally expose as a dependency.  Please correct me if i am wrong.